# NHibernate flatten properties on criterias

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, criteria

I have the following entities:

```
Patient: PatientId, Name, //etc ...

Doctor: DoctorId, Name, //etc...

MedicalConsultation: MedicalConsultationId, Patient, Doctor //(Patient is of type Patient and Doctor is of type Doctor).
```

and the corresponding tables, where MedicalConsultations table has a DoctorId and PatientId as foreign keys.

In NHibernate I need to do something like the following:

```
restrictions.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Like("Doctor.Name", "%" + PartOfDoctorName + "%"));
```

where restrictions is a  IList that holds different restrictions.

When I run this code, it gives back that MedicalConsultation does not have a Doctor.Name property.

I need somehow to flatten the properties : Doctor -> Doctor.Name and add a ICriterion like this to my list of restrictions.

Thanks,
Tamash

Answer (score 0):

i solved this with a second aliaslist

```
HashSet<string> aliases = new HashSet<string>();

restrictions.Add(Expression.Like("Doctor.Name", PartOfDoctorName, Matchmode.EveryWhere));
aliases.Add(Doctor);

...

foreach(string alias in aliases)
    criteria.CreateAlias(alias, alias);

// add restrictions
```